# Connect App Flutter with API instagrame Publish comment

Tags: flutter, api, dart, request, instagram-graph-api

I have a question about connecting my app, made with Flutter, with the Instagram API.

I want the user to register with their account, store the access token and then send a post to the API to publish a comment or add a like.

Can I do this with Flutter or do I need to use a different language like Python?

Answer (score 0):

I checked the [API documentation that Instagram provides](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram) and it seems that you can only do *read-only* requests (liking a post might not be possible).

The API you mentioned in your tags will not work with personal accounts, as Instagram states:

> The API cannot access Instagram consumer accounts (i.e., non-Business or non-Creator Instagram accounts). If you are building an app for consumer users, use the [Instagram Basic Display API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api) instead.

You can try to use the mentioned Basic Display API instead, but mind you won't be able to author any posts or do actions in behalf of the user. To circumvent this, you might have to reverse-engineer the frontend facing portion of Instagram but I won't go into that.

To come back to your question, Flutter is [well able to send network requests as mentioned here](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data), but you still have a long way until you have functioning access to Instagram (check the [Getting Started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started)).